# Timesheet Export

Tags: excel, csv, spreadsheet

I need to export data out of excel worksheet into a CSV format with certain headings, etc. I need this to be user friendly, as it's for timesheets, ideally a button on the spreadsheet would be ideal, does anyone have any experience with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File | Save As | {Choose csv}

You can record that as a macro and add to a button:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/automate-tasks-with-the-macro-recorder-974ef220-f716-4e01-b015-3ea70e64937b